# How can I get the position of a item in ListAdapter of Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I use ListAdapter as the source of a RecyclerView, it will display a list of `MVoice`. You can see Code B.

I think I can get the position of a `MVoice` in ListAdapter, so I can scroll to the position of the item in RecyclerView, just like Code A

Is there a way to get the position of a `Movice`?

**Code A**

```
binding.recyclerViewVoice.adapter = myAdapter
mHomeViewModel.listVoiceBySort.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner) {
  myAdapter.submitList(it)
}
        
//val position=myAdapter.getPostionByItem(aMovice)        
//binding.recyclerViewVoice.scrollToPosition(position)
```

**Code B**

```
class VoiceAdapters (private val aHomeViewModel: HomeViewModel, private val mPlay: PlayInterface):
        ListAdapter<MVoice, VoiceAdapters.VoiceViewHolder>(MVoiceDiffCallback()) {

    private lateinit var mContext: Context
    private lateinit var mLifecycleOwner:LifecycleOwner

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VoiceViewHolder {
        mContext = parent.context
        mLifecycleOwner = mContext as LifecycleOwner

        return VoiceViewHolder(
            LayoutVoiceItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false).also {
               it.lifecycleOwner = mLifecycleOwner
               it.aHomeViewModel = aHomeViewModel
            }
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VoiceViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val inputMVoice = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(inputMVoice)
    }

    inner class VoiceViewHolder (private val binding: LayoutVoiceItemBinding):
          RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(inputMVoice: MVoice) {

            binding.amVoice = inputMVoice

            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }        

}


class MVoiceDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MVoice>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: MVoice, newItem: MVoice): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: MVoice, newItem: MVoice): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a reference to the list currently displayed with `currentList`, and use `indexOf()` to get the position

```
fun getPositionByItem(aMovice: MVoice) = currentList.indexOf(aMovice)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a ItemClick Listener in fun bind(), then pass the MVoice.getPosition in Toast.

Thus you would able to see the position of item in your toast.